# Why isn't windows loading the WINUSB Driver?

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I'm developing a USB Device containing a couple of USB Functions (CDC-ACM and DFU as of now), using windows provided drivers.

The device descriptor indicates the device uses IAD (Interface Association Descriptor) and the configuration descriptor reflects that, containing all the descriptors for the CDC function as well as the DFU Function. This configuration works right out of the box on non-windows platforms, with both drivers correctly assigned.

Due to [WCID (Windows Compatible ID) requirements](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/WCID-Devices), I have setup the following descriptor indicating that windows should load WINUSB for the DFU Interface.

```
USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor msft_compID = 
{
.dwLength =  sizeof(USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor) + (2 * sizeof(USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor_Interface)),

.bcdVersion = 0x0100,
.wIndex = 0x0004,
.bCount = 2,
.interfaces = {
  {
    .bFirstInterfaceNumber = 0, //CDC
    .compatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    .subCompatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  },
  {
    .bFirstInterfaceNumber = INTERFACE_DFU,
    .compatibleID = {0x57, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00},
    .subCompatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  }
}
};
```

When the device is connected, I observed windows requesting for the 0xEE string descriptor followed by a request for the CompatibleID descriptor. The device manager confirms this as shown in the following screenshot. However, the host side software that uses the WINUSB API calls fails to detect the device. When I checked with [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie), it's clear windows had loaded the libusb driver, instead of the winusb I requested.

[image: Screenshot of device manager showing WINUSB as the compatible ID]
[image: Screenshot of Zadig showing libusb driver]

Despite this issue, the CDC-ACM function works as intended with a functioning virtual serial port appearing in the device manager.

Have I made any mistake in the ComaptibleID descriptor configuration, or are there any additional steps to take in order to make sure the correct driver is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after reading between the lines of Microsoft Descriptor documentation. In order for windows to load the WINUSB driver, just the `MicrosoftComaptibleID` descriptor is not sufficient. Windows requires the device to add a DeviceGUID registry entry with the help of another Microsoft specific descriptor.
This can be done under the Microsoft Descriptor Specification 1, but I updated the whole device to support the version 2.0 with the help of this [excellent guide by google.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb)

Therefore my current descriptor structure looks like this.

```
BOS descriptor 
    Bos header 
    WEBusb capability
    Microsoft capability
        Microsoft descriptor set header
```

The BOS descriptor is a part of official USB specification released between 2.0 and 3.0. When windows reads the Microsoft descriptor set header, it requests for the Microsoft descriptor set by the means of a vendor request.

```
MSFTDesc
USB_MSFTDescriptorHeader            
    USB_MSFTConfigurationSubsetHeader   
    USB_MSFTFunctionSubsetHeader        
    USB_MSFTCompatibleIDFeatureDescriptor   
    USB_MSFTRegPropertyDescriptor
```

The Microsoft descriptor set contains the compatible IDs as well as the registry property descriptor for the GUID.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Zadig to see what drivers Windows is using.  The list of SYS files is shown in the Device Manager when you double-click on your device and go to the "Driver" tab.

At some point, possibly through software like Zadig, you might have loaded an INF file on your computer that tells it to use libusb0 with your device.  You can inspect your device in the Device Manager and look at the "Inf Name" field to find out what INF file is responsible for this, if that is the case.

I recommend that you right-click on your device and select "Uninstall Device..." to remove your device's association with libusb0.  You should also click the "Uninstall driver software" checkbox as you are doing this to remove the unwanted INF file (if it exists).

Comment: I have tried this couple of times. First trying the device manager uninstall options, and then later deleting the WCID flags from the registry. Just to be sure I tried with a fresh windows laptop and it wasn't working. (I didn't check which driver the new computer loaded, but the DFU functionality which depends on the winusb didn't work).

Comment: What "Inf Name" does Windows show for your device in the Device Manager?  And what are the "Hardware Ids"?

Comment: I checked with a fresh computer, weirdly enough "inf name" is winusb.inf and "Hardware Ids" show "USB\VID_04D8&PID_EC19&REV_0115&MI_02" and "USB\VID_04D8&PID_EC19&MI_02". Looks like winusb driver is loaded, still dfu-util won't recognize the device.

Comment: So your device is actually using winusb.sys then and your problem is with bugs in dfu-util or not knowing how it works.  I can't help with dfu-util. Maybe ask a new question with an appropriate title.

Comment: I'm really not sure what's going on here, because on the first computer I tried it loaded libusb0, and dfu-util started working flawlessly once I switched to winusb manually using Zadig